# Filename as a String getParent and getName isn't it

Tags: string, filenames

How can I get Desktop/1.txt as a String

```
File f = new File("/home/jigar/Desktop/1.txt");
System.out.println(f.getParent());// /home/jigar/Desktop
System.out.println(f.getName());  //1.txt
```

Comment: can you please explain what do you want exactly as question is confusing?

Comment: I want a String "Desktop/1.txt"